# CSV shows weird apostrophe in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have included CSV import feature in my rails app. But the issue I am facing is if there is any industry with includes apostrophe in title, it shows up weird in CSV. How can I add meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" so that CSV includes apostrophe.

```
CSV_HEADER = %w[title role team]



def self.to_csv
      CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << CSV_HEADER
      all.each do |industry|
      csv << [
        industry.title,        
        industry.role, 
        industry.team
       ]
      end
    end 
 end


<%= link_to "Download CSV", admin_path(@industry, :format => :csv, :filterrific => @filterrific.to_hash), class: "btn btn-primary btn-2x" %>
```

controller action

```
def application
    require 'csv'

    add_breadcrumb "Admin", :main_admin_path
    add_breadcrumb "Industrial Applications"
    @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
      Industry,
      params[:filterrific],
      select_options: {
    with_status: Industry.options_for_status
        }
    )   or return   
    @industries = @filterrific.find
    @industries = @industries.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10) unless request.format == 'csv' #does pagination if not csv format

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.csv { send_data @industries.to_csv, :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present' }
    end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
        puts "Had to reset filterrific params: #{ e.message }"
        redirect_to(reset_filterrific_url(format: :html)) and return            
end
```

Comment: @engineersmnky sorry it was a typing error. it is industry not funding.

Comment: Can you show your controller action?

Comment: @engineersmnky added controller action

Comment: to set the content type etc. you need to pass options to the `send_data` method  https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data

Comment: @engineersmnky i have added :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present' but it still shows weird apostrophe in CSV

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "weird apostrophe"?

Comment: @engineersmnky So when I download the csv the Children's Toy factory appear like this in the csv Childrenâ€™s Toy Factory. Hope I could explain myself

Comment: @engineersmnky any idea? I still couldn't figureout

Answer (score 0):

The concept of BOM(byte order mark) was used to fix this issue.

```
format.csv { send_data "\uFEFF" + @industries.to_csv, type: :csv }
```